# How can I exclude files of the Code Coverage of SonarQube using JaCoCo maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jacoco-maven-plugin

I've got a big issue with the integration of JaCoCo maven plugin for the code covering of SonarQube 6.0.

I've got a multi-module Maven project lets say :

```
master
    |--core
    |--web
    |--process
```

in the master pom.xml, I've setted a reporting profile like that :

```
<profile>
        <id>reporting</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                            <!--<phase>test</phase> -->
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to the file to write the execution data to. -->
                                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                                <!-- Connection with SureFire plugin -->
                                <propertyName>sonarUnitTestArgLine</propertyName>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>post-unit-test</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <!-- Sets the path to where the execution data is located. -->
                                <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                                <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                                <outputDirectory>${jacoco.ut.outputdir}</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                        <argLine>${sonarUnitTestArgLine} -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -Xms512m -Xmx512m</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

in the childs, I overload the configuration by adding some exclusions :

```
<!-- First attempt -->
<properties>
    <sonar.jacoco.excludes>**/model/**/*</sonar.jacoco.excludes>
</properties>

<!-- Second attempt -->
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>**/model/**/*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>

<!-- Third attempt -->
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>reporting</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- Exclude model classes (POJO's) -->
                            <exclude>**/model/**/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

the idea here is to remove the Pojo of the code coverage ( we also do it for other types of Class ...)

When I run the mvn command line :

```
mvn clean generate-sources install verify -P reporting -fn
```

All my reports are well generated but in Sonar, the exculsions aren't been taking into account ...

Please can you help me fixing this issue ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After a lot of reasearch, I've found the solution for this problem, I post the answers to help poeple ho'll have the same issue :

In the master-module

```
<properties>
    <sonar.coverage.exclusions>
       **/patternA/**/*,
       **/patternB/**/*
    </sonar.coverage.exclusions>
</properties>
```

In the sub-modules

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>report</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <!-- Exclude model classes (POJO's) -->
                            <exclude>**/patternA/**/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

in the master pom

Comment: I do not get it. Why do you need to do it twice?

Comment: II can put it only once on the Master Pom, but I don't find that answers very robust. But it's still a way to avoid the issue ...

Comment: @k0ner one excludes it from being instrumented by jacoco, the other hides it from the sonar report.

Answer (score 4):

I tried adding just the below details in properties section and it worked for me.

```
<sonar.coverage.exclusions>
     **/patternA/*.java,
     **/patternB/*.java
</sonar.coverage.exclusions>
```